# What is a suitable tag for questions on a specific biblical passage?

Tags: discussion, tags

I propose that questions such as [What is the message of Matthew 9:5?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-message-of-matthew-95) should be tagged as something like 'specific-scripture-reference' or 'passage-interpretation' to make tags more relevant.

What others think on creating one of those tags or something similar and re-tagging the questions on interpretation of a specific Bible passage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd call this [exegesis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis). Possibly [biblical-exegesis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-exegesis), but I think that's pretty implicit from the nature of the site.

Comment: probably a good plan to use a more technical term and synonomize [tag:interpretation] and [tag:biblical-interpretation] to this one.

Comment: +1 for the answer for now. I think that is the right word, but is an academic word. But I wonder how many ordinary members of the site will get it and understand it to tag under 'exegesis' or biblical-exegesis.

Comment: @Jamess So we can retag it -- it's not difficult. And if people learn a new word, cool! That's what these sites should be about!

Comment: @lonesomeday Agreed on your view.